# How to find the image of linear transformation of a tilted ellipse?

Tags: linear-transformations

I am trying to solve the image of a tilted ellipse
$x^2+3y^2-3xy-8x+10y+1=0$ under the linear transformation represented by the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\1&3\end{bmatrix}$

Since there are six terms in the given equation, I am thinking of finding 6 points on the curve and find their respective image using the given matrix and find the values of the numerical coefficients of the following equation.

$ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f=0$

I would like to kindly ask if my solution is possible and if there are other simpler ways to find the image of the linear transformation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at Roberts answer here- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200569/geometrically-explained-why-do-linear-transformations-take-a-circle-to-an-ellip, and just make your changes in the circle equation (multiply it by the respective matrices to make it an ellipse)

Comment: @OrShahar, Thank you for sharing this past questions and Robert's answer.
I got the idea but could you give some hint on how I can use the given to transform it into a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the ellipse as $$[x,y,1]\begin{bmatrix}1&-3/2&-4\\-3/2&3&5\\-4&5&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1 \end{bmatrix}=0.$$Make the linear transformation $$\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime}\\y^{\prime} \\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\1&3&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$Note that the inverse of $$\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\1&3&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}-3/4&1/4&0\\1/4&1/4&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you! May I kindly ask, why do we need the inverse if what we need is to find $\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime}\\y^{\prime} \\1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Do I need to express $[x,y,1]$ and $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \\1\end{bmatrix}$ in terms of $\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime}\\y^{\prime} \\1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong.

$\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime}\\y^{\prime} \\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\1&3&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \\1\end{bmatrix}$.
Hence, 



$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \\1\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix}-3&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime}\\y^{\prime} \\1\end{bmatrix}$

$[x,y,1] = \frac{1}{4} [x^{\prime},y^{\prime},1]\begin{bmatrix}-3&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&4 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Based on the first matrix equation, the answer must be

$\frac{1}{16} [x^{\prime},y^{\prime},1]\begin{bmatrix}-3&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&-3/2&-4\\-3/2&3&5\\-4&5&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-3&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime}\\y^{\prime} \\1\end{bmatrix}=0$

Comment: @PRD: Suppose we have a conic $$[x y 1]M\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}=0.$$Suppose also that we have an invertible transformation $$\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime}\\y^{\prime}\\1\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Suppose that $(a,b)$ is a point on the conic and that $(\alpha,\beta)$ is its image under the transformation ,so $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\1\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$[a b 1]M\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\1\end{bmatrix}=0.$$ contnued innext comment

Comment: Since $$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\1\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\1\end{bmatrix},$$ we have $$[\alpha \beta 1](P^{-1})^TMP^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\1\end{bmatrix}=0.$$ Thus the transformed point $(\alpha,\beta)$ lies on the conic $$[x y 1](P^{-1})^TMP^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}=0.$$